# ASP.NET MVC HtmlHelper extension method to wrap around only if it has content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am making an configurable form—an admin selects which inputs are displayed. The inputs are wrapped by fieldsets.

I want to make a HtmlHelper to generate fieldset only if it has content—at least one input field to prevent such situations

```
<fieldset id="Name">
   <legend>Name</legend>
   <input type="text" placeholer="Forename"></input>
   <input type="text" placeholer="Surname"></input>
</fieldset>


<fieldset id="Address">
   <legend>Address</legend>
</fieldset>
```

that we have empty fieldset like that with address.

I've made a FieldSetHelper

```
public class FieldSetHelper: IDisposable
{
    private readonly HtmlHelper _htmlHelper;
    private readonly string _fieldSetId;
    private readonly string _legendId;
    private readonly string _legendText;

    public FieldSetHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string fieldSetId, string legendId, string legendText)
    {
        _htmlHelper = htmlHelper;
        _fieldSetId = fieldSetId;
        _legendId = legendId;
        _legendText = legendText;

        _htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer = new StringWriter();

        OpenFieldSet();
        AddLegend();
    }

    private void OpenFieldSet()
    {
        string id = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_fieldSetId) ? string.Empty : string.Format(" id=\"{0}\"", _fieldSetId);
        _htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine(string.Format("<fieldset" + id + ">"));
    }

    private void CloseFieldSet()
    {
        _htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine(string.Format("</fieldset>"));
    }

    private void AddLegend()
    {
        string id = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_legendId) ? string.Empty : string.Format(" id=\"{0}\"", _legendId);
        _htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine("<legend"+id+">");
        _htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine(_legendText);
        _htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine("</legend>");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        CloseFieldSet();
    }
```

But I don't know how to not generate it if its content is empty.
Here is part of the View:

```
using (Html.BeginFieldSet("Address", null, "Address"))
{
   @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Address, new {Model.VisibleInputFields})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar situation. I was trying to add some "No Items Here" text if the outer element (the one generated from the using element) did not have any items. This is an untested modified version of what I ended up doing but if you are still looking for an answer it should get you close.

```
 public class FieldSetHelper: IDisposable
{
    private readonly HtmlHelper _htmlHelper;
    private readonly string _fieldSetId;
    private readonly string _legendId;
    private readonly string _legendText;

    public FieldSetHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string fieldSetId, string legendId, string legendText)
    {
        _htmlHelper = htmlHelper;
        _fieldSetId = fieldSetId;
        _legendId = legendId;
        _legendText = legendText;

        _htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer = new StringWriter();

        OpenFieldSet();
        AddLegend();
    }


    private string BuildOpenFieldSetString(){
        string id = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_fieldSetId) ? string.Empty : string.Format(" id=\"{0}\"", _fieldSetId);
        return string.Format("<fieldset" + id + ">");
    }

    private void OpenFieldSet()
    {
        _htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine(BuildOpenFieldSetString());
    }

    private void CloseFieldSet()
    {
        _htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine(string.Format("</fieldset>"));
    }

    private void AddLegend()
    {
        string id = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_legendId) ? string.Empty : string.Format(" id=\"{0}\"", _legendId);
        _htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine("<legend"+id+">");
        _htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine(_legendText);
        _htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine("</legend>");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        var htmlString = _htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.ToString();
        var index = htmlString.Trim().LastIndexOf(BuildOpenFieldSetString().Trim());
        if(html.IndexOf("<input", index) == -1){
            _htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer = new StringWriter();
            _htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine(html.SubString(0,index));
        }else{
            CloseFieldSet();
        }
    }
```